# Delphi PSafeArray out parameter in DLL wrapper

Tags: delphi, dll, com, activex

I have to call a procedure which is declared in the type library as follows:

```
procedure getDataFromMem(const mem: IMemory; Max: Integer; out data: PSafeArray); safecall;
```

When I call it, I receive a handled exception from the DLL. Is there any specific I have to do with the PSafeArray parameter? Do I need to initialize it somehow?

My actual code is the following:

```
var
  mem: X_TLB.IMemory;
  a: PSafeArray;
  uprod: X_TLB.IProduct;
begin
  uprod:=(m_Prod as IProduct);
  mem := uprod.GetFull(1);
  uprod.getDataFromMem(mem,256,a);
end;
```

Comment: Please show the code you are using to call the procedure.  You don't have to initialize the parameter as it is marked as `out`, so the procedure is responsible for initializing it. Besides, the Delphi compiler initializes `out` parameters for you anyway.

Comment: Yes, I know what is out parameter. But PSafeArray is something that I didn't have to use yet. And I've read some mysteries about it.

Comment: I found this article easy to read and follow: http://blog.virtec.org/2008/07/the-mysteries-of-psafearray/

Comment: You are passing an uninitialized `IMemory` in the 1st parameter

Comment: Remy, of-course I initialize the mem parameter, but it's not related to the question. Thank you for your answer anyway.

Comment: Rudy, I've read that article, but it not about out PSafeArray parameter, only about how to create and initialize a PSafeArray.

Comment: I can't for the life of me understand this question. What are you asking? Are you asking about the exception? If so, you've provided no details of it whatsoever, and no details of how this function is meant to be called. Perhaps your arguments are wrong. How can we know that. What does the documentation for the library say? We can't see it. Why have you assumed that the only issue is the use of a specific type?

Comment: David, my question was quite simple: do I need to initialize a PSafeArray when it is an out parameter. It seems I don't have to. Thanks for your cooperation.

Comment: You could have worked that out by reading the docs for out parameters. I thought you were asking more.

Comment: David, you could also get the point by reading my question.